# Changing default email to some other email client while sending email in iphone/ipad app (in non built-in app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, email-client

If I were to send an email from any ios app (non built in apps) then can I change
'from' (some default id) to some other id. 
Say gmail is my default email set up in MAIL App. So can I use my other email account to send 
email even if I use gmail as default mailing option.

I am looking to implement this functionality for my ios app.

Is it possible and is there any way to achieve this using coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method for this listed in the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) on MFMailComposer, and Apple does not like people messing with MFMailComposer. So no.

From the documentation:

`The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.`